# data-ajax-update not working in dotnet core jquery unobtrusive ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to update the data in my container with ajax data from a partial view but the page just reloads without errors and doesn't update the data. Please help me with advice.

Its my controller code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult OnGetPartial()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**Its my PartialView code**

```
<p>Hello from the Hello World partial at @DateTime.Now</p>
```

**its my index and _layout code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - IntegTest</title>              
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
            @RenderBody()       
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>              
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
        </script>                 
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>    
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Index**

```
<a href="" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("OnGetPartial","Home")" data-ajax-update="#panel" data-ajax-complete="completed" data-ajax-failure="failed">Click Here!</a>
<div id="panel">        
</div>
<script>
    completed = function (xhr) {
        alert('hi ${xhr.responseText}!');
    }
    failed = function (xhr) {
        alert('Status: { xhr.status }, Status Text: { xhr.statusText}');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX library , it can be find in Github :

https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

You can download the file from above link(in src folder) or install it from Nuget in VS . Then you need to link the file in your _layout page :

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

After that your code should works well . In addition , you should ensure you have set correct partial view name . If you are using Razor pages , you can refer to [this article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax) for detail code sample .

Comment: Oh my God, I spent 2 days reading all the articles I could find about this library and just didn't plug it in... I checked my code 200 times... I loathe myself so much that I want to bash my head against the wall.

Comment: thank you very much kind person, I am very grateful for the answer, long life to you. Thanks

Comment: I had exactly the same issue as @vlad